# Filter Toolbar without loadonce:true?

Tags: filter, jqgrid, toolbar

I am using jqgrid, with filter toolbar(column) option...The total data is around 10,000...So it seems to be some delay in initial loading as the config is set to loadonce:true;

Any way to implement the filter column feature with loadonce:false ?
Because the data loading delay is okay with loadonce:false. If I get a chance to add column filter with loadonce:false, this will work perfectly...

Answer (score 4):

If you has about 10,000 rows it is of course better to implement server side data paging, sorting and filtering. I recommend you to use [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching#calling_convention) with the parameter `stringResult:true` if you not already use it. In the case jqGrid will send to the server `filters` parameter in the same format like advanced searching as [do](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options). So you will need implement on the server side the method which use following input parameter from jqGrid:

- `sidx` and `sord` parameters define the sort order of the data. The informations specify `ORDER BY` in the corresponding `SELECT` statement.
- if `_search` parameter is `true`, then the next parameter `filters` gives additional information which construct the `WHERE` part of the corresponding `SELECT` statement.
- `page` and `rows` parameters define which page of the data previously sorted and filtered should be returned.

The exact implementation is depend on the language and technology which you use on the server and of course which database server and which interface to the database you use.

Comment: This is my grid initialization. I already used stringResult:true, but not worked...Currently it loads all 10000 data initially and all other actions are performing based on the initial data in xml format...So it needs a lot time to load grid. I just need to filter toolbar directly from the server. If I type anything in filter toolbar, it should check the data from the server, not from the all data loaded initially as in xml format.

Comment: @George: You should just remove `loadonce:true`. In the first request you will have rows=20&page=1&sidx=fireform_respondent.id&sord=asc. You server should use ORDER BY fireform_respondent.id and LIMIT 0,20 (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#php_and_mysql_example_file)). You can load Demo Files from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 for PHP more examples. In search_adv.php you fill find how to decode `filters` parameter which will be send by `filterToolbar` and how use it in the `WHERE` part of `SELECT` to get back only filtered data.

Comment: If I remove the loadonce:true, the filter toolbar will not work, that means it will not sort out the data based on the keywords...But If we use loadonce:true it will sortout data while we type some thing in the toolbar search field...My aim is to find a solution to this...that means when I type anything on the toolbar search field it should directly send the request to server and findout the data from the database.

Comment: @George: You should decide whether you want work with the server and get latest data from the server, then you should use implement data filtering on the server. The server receive additional parameters. In case of `stringResult: true` it is one parameter `filter` and the server should construct `WHERE` based on the the value of `filter` parameter. In the file `search_adv.php` from the demo http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/downloads/jqgrid_demo38.zip you will find the code example how to do this. Then you can remove `loadonce:true` and all will work perfect.

Comment: @George: The format of the `filters` parameter in case of the usage of `stringResult: true` is the same as for advanced searching and described here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options